# Powered USB hub sometimes locks up Macbook Pro on being plugged in

Tags: macos, keyboard, usb, performance, trackpad

I have a Plugable 7-port powered USB 3.0 hub.  I use it to connect my external hard drives (I have three) to my Macbook Pro (that has only 2 USB 3.0 ports).

Sometimes, when I plug the hub into my Mac, it'll just hang up, and the keyboard and trackpad become complete unresponsive.  However, everything else seems to be working normally (music is still playing, downloads are being done, notifications pop up, general screen activity is normal).

It's happened several times now and is really annoying as I fear it could soon corrupt the information on my hard drives (especially since I run VMs off the externals).

Is there any way I can diagnose the problem/check system logs or anything?

Comment: And you are sure your powered USB hub has enough power and not killing your USB on the Mac.

Comment: I've used it on a Windows laptop for a long time without any problem...

Comment: Could you look up in About this Mac for how much current is the USB assigned to it.

Comment: USB 3.0 Hub:
....
Current Available (mA): 900
Current Required (mA): 0
...
Backup+ disk:
...
Current Available (mA): 900
Current Required (mA): 144